# The add command requires to be run in an Angular project

Tags: angular

While adding a component in project getting below error.

> The add command requires to be run in an Angular project, but a
> project definition could not be found

Answer (score 1):

You have to create a project first.

```sh
ng new myprojectname
```

After having done this, you can go into the project folder:

```sh
cd myprojectname
```

And then/there you can do something with `add`.